# jQuery return to page on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I currently have a div that contains text and have the text changing upon the click function of my secondary navigation (which is Owl carousel).

Once the page is refreshed I wish for the text to return to its original, default state. I can find instructions on how to make a refresh button for jQuery, but I do not wish to use a button, just the refresh in the browser. Am I trying to do the impossible? What kind of script or code could I turn to accomplish this?

Here are a few things I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div[data-role*='page']").live('pagehide', function(event, ui) {
          if ($(this).children("div[data-role*='content']").is(".command-no-cache"))
              $(this).remove();
});
});
```

Another attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
refresh = function (selector)
{
try
{            
$('#TextLeft').html('refresh'); 
}
catch (e) 
{
}
});
```

HTML MARKUP

```
 <div class="ImageRight">
 <img src="links/00-PlaceholderLarge.jpg"/>
 </div>

<div class="TextLeft">

<div class="headline">
    <img src="links/AboutUs.png"/>
 </div>

<div class="lineGreen"></div>

<div class="tabs">

<div id="about">    
<h3>Headline</h3>
<p>TEXT</p>
</div>

<div id="first">
<h3>Headline</h3>
<p>TEXT</p>
</div>

<div id="second">
<h3>Headline</h3>
<p>TEXT</p>
</div>

<div id="third">
<h3>Headline</h3>
<p>TEXT</p>
</div>    

</div>    
</div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div id="Gray">
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

<div class="ImageContainer Purple">
      <div id="PurpleColor">
          <h2>TITLE</h2> 
  </div>

            <div  class="photo grow">  
             <a href="#first" id="1">           
                <img src="links/AboutUs-IMG1.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>

        <div class="ImageFooter" id="Purple">
          <p class="ImageContainerP">Headline</p>
        </div>
  </div>

<div class="ImageContainer Green">
        <div id="GreenColor">
          <h2>TITLE</h2>
        </div>

       <div class="photo grow">
          <a href="#second" id="2">
            <img src="links/AboutUs-IMG2.jpg"/>
          </a>
       </div>

        <div class="ImageFooter" id="Green">
          <p class="ImageContainerP">Headline</p>
  </div></div>

<div class="ImageContainer Blue">
        <div id="BlueColor">
          <h2>TITLE</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="photo grow">
        <a href="#third" id="3">
            <img src="links/AboutUs-IMG3.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="ImageFooter" id="Blue">
          <p class="ImageContainerP">Headline</p>
        </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: please post the code you have tried so far

Comment: Can't you just add some script that executes on the document/window ready event, which reverts the text back to its default value? You need to provide a clearer problem statement and a previous attempt, for us to have enough information to give a proper answer.

Comment: Could you give us the HTML for the div? I don't understand why the div would not return to its original state when you do a page refresh. That should not keep any changes done to the DOM by JavaScript.

Comment: I've posted some additional code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to answer your question completely without all of the code. If you set up a jsfiddle it would be easier. Anyway... I would just add a class with the click function that adds the necessary changes to your text. If the class is not present in the HTML markup and only gets added by the JS on click, it will not be present on page load. That should solve your problem. I cant really be more specific without knowing exactly what your on-click function does or more specifics about your page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the confusion - upon additional research I found I was asking the wrong question. I am using hash to scroll through the owl carousel and all I had to do was clear the hash on reload: location.hash = ""; Live and learn, I suppose.